# Combining tables with different attributes and size in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the three following tables:

```
Product(manufacturer,model,type)
Laptop(model,speed,ram,hd,price)
Printer (model,color,type,price)
```

As you can see the product table contains the name of manufacturers and the model number of the products they make. The type attributes just specifies if is a printer or Laptop.
**Now let's say as a user I want to find all the products (both laptops and printers) that manufacturer 'A' makes and the output should be one table.**  using an SQL statement.

The thing I am confused about is how combine two tables with different attributes and column sizes.
As of now, I just found the laptop and pc models for manufacturer 'A':

```
SELECT * from Product P , Laptop L where P.model = L.model
SELECT * from Product P, Printer PR where P.model = PR.model
```

Note that  these are two separate queries. I just do not know how I would combine them. Tried `UNION` but that did not help

EDIT: The problem states that I need to print the model number, the product type, and all of the attributes of whichever relation is appropriate for that type.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` with `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT p.manufacturer, p.model, p.type
FROM product p
WHERE p.manufacturer = 'A' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM laptop l WHERE l.model = p.model)
UNION ALL -- USE "UNION" IN ORDER TO REMOVE DUPLICATE ROW
SELECT p.manufacturer, p.model, p.type
FROM product p
WHERE p.manufacturer = 'A' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Printer pr WHERE pr.model = p.model);
```

Answer (score 0):

use left join

```
   select p.*,l.*,pr.* from Product p left join Laptop l on p.model=l.model
                      left join printer pr on pr.model=p.model
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` clause then give your join condition and after that `where` condition . I hope it will be work for you .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do:

```
select p.*
from product p
where p.manufacturer = 'A' and
      (exists (select 1
               from laptop l
               where l.model = p.model and l.type = 'laptop'
              ) or
       exists (select 1
               from printer pr
               where pr.model = p.model and pr.type = 'printer'
              )
      );
```

However, it seems like you could just do:

```
select p.*
from product p
where p.type in ('laptop', 'printer');
```

If you want to bring in additional attributes, use `union all` like this:

```
select p.*, lp.*
from product p join
     ((select model, type, price
       from laptop
      ) union all
      (select model, type, price
       from printer
      )
     ) lp
     on lp.model = p.model and lp.type = p.type;
```